# WebView events not firing in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I want to get the HTML from a WebView page, so I make use of the EvaluateJavaScriptAsync function to get the body. However, this throws an NRE, probably because I am fetching the document before the page has loaded. Hence, I add a lambda expression to the `Navigated`
event.

```cs
var wv = new WebView();
wv.Source = "https://www.bbc.com/news";
wv.Navigated += async (s, e) =>
{
    var x = await wv.EvaluateJavaScriptAsync("document.body.innerHTML");
    Debugger.Break();
};
```

However, the execution never `break`s, i.e. the `Navigated` event is not getting fired. I've tried other events, and realised the `Navigating` event also never fires. This doesn't work for any other website as well. Any idea of what's going on?

Alternatively, is there any other way to do dynamic web scraping in Xamarin that wouldn't be too computationally expensive on mobile? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a demo about getting the html from webview page by using `CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync()`.

```
public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
     
            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                this.webView2.Source = new System.Uri(textBox1.Text, System.UriKind.Absolute);
            }
            private async void webView2_NavigationCompleted(object sender, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs e)
            {
     
                object obj = await webView2.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.body.innerHTML");
                textBox2.Text = obj.ToString();
            }
     
            private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                object obj = await webView2.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.body.innerHTML");
                textBox2.Text = obj.ToString();
            }
     
     
     
            private async void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                object obj = await webView2.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.body.innerText");
                textBox2.Text = obj.ToString();
            }
     
            private async void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                object obj = await webView2.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("$('.f3')[0].innerHTML");
                textBox2.Text = obj.ToString();
            }
```

Comment: Isn't CoreWebView2 only for WPF and not mobile applications?